# Why is VideoView not importing properly in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview, findviewbyid

[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiWND.png)

I am taking an android development course through coursera and cannot figure out why import android.widget.VideoView is gray as though it is not working and findViewById is showing an error.

Comment: Please provide us the error message

Answer (score 1):

Try this `val videoView: VideoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.textView)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the view when calling findViewById(), either this way

```
val videoView: VideoView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

or this way

```
val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.textView)
```

It's not a problem with the import, if you check the error, you will see that the error is

```
"Not enough information to infer parameter T"
```